# How to make communication between ParentFragment and Appolica Interactive InfoWindow Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, infowindow

I tried to use callback to communicate between my fragments but it seems that infowindowfragment does not recognize my mapFragment as its parentfragment, is there something I can do to work or have another way to do this?

Mapfragment (parentFragment):

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements MapView, OnMapReadyCallback, //GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
        ,InfoWindowFragment.OnChildFragmentInteractionListener{
```

...

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mapInfoWindowFragment =
            (MapInfoWindowFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapInfoWindowFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
```

...

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    setOnMakerClick(map);
    moveCameraToLastKnowLocation();
}
```

...

```
public void setOnMakerClick(final GoogleMap googleMap){
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            NearDriver nearDriver = markers.get(marker);
            LatLng position = new LatLng(nearDriver.getLatitude()+0.007, nearDriver.getLongitude());
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));

            //marker.showInfoWindow();

            final int offsetX = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.marker_offset_x);
            final int offsetY = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.marker_offset_y);

            final InfoWindow.MarkerSpecification markerSpec =
                    new InfoWindow.MarkerSpecification(offsetX, offsetY);

            InfoWindowFragment infoWindowFragment = new InfoWindowFragment();

            final InfoWindow infoWindow = new InfoWindow(marker, markerSpec, infoWindowFragment);

            mapInfoWindowFragment.infoWindowManager().toggle(infoWindow, true);
            infoWindowFragment.render(nearDriver);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

...

```
@Override
public void messageFromChildToParent(Place place) {
    Log.d("d", "MapFragment - Place: " + place.getName());
    setOnMakerClick(map);

}
```

InfoWindowFragment ("ChildFragment"):

```
public interface OnChildFragmentInteractionListener {
    void messageFromChildToParent(Place place);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    // check if parent Fragment implements listener
    if (getParentFragment() instanceof OnChildFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mParentListener = (OnChildFragmentInteractionListener) getParentFragment();
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("The parent fragment must implement OnChildFragmentInteractionListener");
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
06-13 00:53:57.427 18791-18791/com.rsm.yuri.projecttaxilivre E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rsm.yuri.projecttaxilivre, PID: 18791
java.lang.RuntimeException: The parent fragment must implement OnChildFragmentInteractionListener
    at com.rsm.yuri.projecttaxilivre.map.InteractiveInfoWindow.InfoWindowFragment.onAttach(InfoWindowFragment.java:175)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the way to access the mapfragment:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
        MapFragment parentFragment = mainActivity.getMapFragment();
        if (parentFragment != null) {
            mParentListener = (OnChildFragmentInteractionListener) parentFragment;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("The parent fragment must implement OnChildFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

}
```